# Let $I$ be a line interval and $f: I \to \mathbb{R} $ continuous show that if $f(I) \subseteq \mathbb{Q} $ then $f$ is constant.

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, continuity

Since $f$ is continuous it maps intervals to intervals. Since $f(I) \subseteq \mathbb{Q} $ no element of $\mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q}$ is element of $f(I)$. The irrationals are dense in $\mathbb{R}$ therefore $f(I)$ need to be a single point in $\mathbb{Q}$ therefore constant.

Is that a valid proof? probably not very well written. Tips o improve are welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty much - I would accept your proof though for explicitness you can spell it out, i.e.

Let $I = [a,b]$ for some $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ with $a < b$ and suppose that there were two points both in the interval, $x_1$ and $x_2$, with the first less than the second, such that $f(x1) \ne f(x_2)$ and W.L.O.G. - by considering $-f$ if necessary - $f(x_1) < f(x_2)$.

Then on $[x_1,x_2]$ $f$ obtains every value in $[f(x_1),f(x_2)]$ by the I.V.T., as connected sets are taken to connected sets, but any non-trivial interval has an irrational number in it, from which it follows that the image of f cannot be a subset of the rational numbers.

Answer (score 2):

This is definitely right idea. I would phrase it as "the only real intervals in $\mathbb{Q}$ are singletons, and $f(I)$ is an interval in $\mathbb{Q}$. So $f(I)$ is a singleton.